# Opening new notebooks with a non-default window size

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, customization

I'd like to set *Mathematica* (8.0.4.0) up so it opens new notebooks with the `"NaturalColor"` stylesheet and with a `WindowSize` like `{800,770}`. 
I tried to change default stylesheet via:

`OptionInspector -> Global Preferences -> Global Options\File Locations\Default Style Definition`

and I get this [ugly notebook](http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=767354)
instead of [this one](http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=767355).

And when I Change the value of `"WindowSize"` from `"Medium"` to `"{800,770}"` under `"Notebook Options\Window Properties"`, it just does nothing.

This is driving me crazy, any ideas ?

Answer (score 12):

The default window size can be controlled from two different places.  The first is the Global `$FrontEnd` WindowSize, set through the `Option Inspector > Global Preferences` or with:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, WindowSize -> {300, 900}]
```

The second is the WindowSize of the style sheet itself.  *If it is defined, the WindowSize of the style sheet will overrule the setting above.*  You set the style sheet size through the `Option Inspector > Selected Notebook` or by evaluating this inside the style sheet itself:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> {300, 900}]
```

To select the default style sheet, click the button to the right of the setting name, and use the file browser:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: window size and window position cannot be set globally for newly opened notebooks. Had this confirmed by Wolfram after a couple of other questions here asking similar. You can only set these at the notebook level, i.e. the notebook has to open *first* at its default position with default size before you can change these settings.

Comment: @Mike, I just tested this again to make sure I'm not blowing smoke.  It works as I described.  Are you *sure* the style sheet doesn't have a WindowSize setting embedded in it that is overriding the global setting?

Comment: Maybe we are talking apples and oranges -- what did you test? I was talking about an inability to globally set a window size for all notebooks via e.g. a global setting in the option inspector (or equivalent code). It is possible to set default sizes for various dialog boxes globally but not for notebooks. I am on Mac but when I asked Wolfram I also asked about Windows since it was originally a Windows question on here that alerted me to this absence. Ditto the `WindowMargins`.

Comment: @Mike your insistence caused me to look at this once again, and the situation is more complicated than I thought.  I *always* create a new notebook with a button that calls `NotebookCreate[StyleDefinitions -> . . .]` and this produces *different behavior* than using `File > New > Notebook`.  With this it *is* possible to get the specified Notebook WindowSize, and theoretically one could edit MenuSetup.tr to get the same result from the menu.  I shall try to update my answer today with a more complete analysis of how this works.

Comment: Yes it would be possible to do it that way because you are setting the specific notebook option within the notebook you create. I guess I was referring to the current built in availability rather than buttons a user can create.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question: To change the style definition for the default notebook, youe need to change the  value of the `OptionInspector -> Global Preferences -> Global Options\File Locations\Default Style Definition` to

```
 FrontEnd`FileName[{"Creative"}, "NaturalColor.nb"]
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** that you need to hit `Enter` after you type anything in an input field in the `Options Inspector`. Clicking on the `Apply` button or anywhere outside the input field without hitting `Enter` just resets the field value.

Comment: It worked for the Stylesheet but, the windows are still opened in {707, 639} whenever I hit Ctrl+N ... and the value under "Option Inspector > Selected Notebook >Window Properties" returns to : " {825, FEPrivate`If[FEPrivate`SameQ[FEPrivate`$OperatingSystem, "Unix"], 11, 0] + FEPrivate`If[FEPrivate`SameQ[FEPrivate`Less[FEPrivate`$DaysUntilExpiration, 15], True], 505, 451]} " upon restart

Comment: @user1234161, re window sizes for new notebooks please see Mike's comments on Mr.Wizard's answer.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read here on MSE, it is not possible to create a default WindowSize for new notebooks. To cope with this efficiently, I've created the following palette which others might find handy as well.

The result looks like this:

[image]

And the full code is:

```
(* Screen sizing buttons *)

fullscreen = 
 Button[Text[Style["Full Screen", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Full}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

autosize = Button[Text[Style["Auto Size", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Automatic}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

medsize = Button[Text[Style["Med size", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Medium}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

windowTwoThirds = 
 Button[Text[Style["2/3 width", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Scaled[2/3], Scaled[.98]},
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

windowOneHalf = 
 Button[Text[Style["1/2 width", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Scaled[1/2], Scaled[.98]},
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

windowOneThird = 
 Button[Text[Style["1/3 width", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Scaled[1/3], Scaled[.98]},
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

maxwindow = Button[Text[Style["Max size", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]},
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

maxwidth = Button["\[LeftRightArrow]",
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowSize -> {Scaled[1], Automatic}(*WindowMargins\[Rule]{{0,
   Automatic},{Automatic,0}}*)], BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium]

maxheight = 
 Button[Text[Style["\[UpDownArrow]", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Automatic, Scaled[1]}
   (*WindowMargins\[Rule]{{0,Automatic},{Automatic,0}}*)], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

(* Screen movement buttons *)

movetopleft = 
 Button[Text[
   Style["\[UpperLeftArrow] Move", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

movetopright = 
 Button[Text[
   Style["Move \[UpperRightArrow]", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], 
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

movebottomright = 
 Button[Text[
   Style["Move \[LowerRightArrow]", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], 
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 0}, {0, Automatic}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

movebottomleft = 
 Button[Text[
   Style["\[LowerLeftArrow] Move", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], 
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

(* Create palette *)

CreatePalette[Row@{
   (*Grid@{{unlockCell,quitKernel,redColor},{lockCell, "",clearColor}},*)

   Grid@{{fullscreen, maxwindow, autosize}, {windowTwoThirds, windowOneHalf, 
      windowOneThird}},
   Grid@{{maxheight}, {maxwidth}},
   Grid@{{movetopleft,
      movetopright},
     {movebottomleft,
      movebottomright}}
   },
 WindowTitle -> "Screen management"
 ]
```

One the palette has been shown up as a dialog window in Mathematica, you should use (menu) > Palettes > Install palette...  to ensure it is always available under the Palettes menu.

Comment: I have never found this palette useful until I bought a 34-inch ultra wide screen couple weeks ago. It is a must have feature to have on such wide display. Thanks for sharing.