# How can I change the style of every newly opened notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, stylesheet

I'd like to make *Mathematica* open a new notebook using the Natural Color template (under the Creative category) by default. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: You can set the `"DefaultStyleDefinitions"` option in the Options Inspector.

Comment: I set the "DefaultStyleDefinitions" (under Global Options->File Locations) so that, instead of "Default.nb" it pointed to "NaturalColor.nb" and I get some crazy worksheet (army green background, pink input boxes). I'd attach a screenshot, but I don't know how (first posting to stackexchange). I think that there are things inherited from Default.nb that are not present in NaturalColor.nb.

Comment: I don't remember, but you might have to point it to `"Creative/NaturalColor.nb"`

Comment: YES! Thanks so much. That did the trick! (I'm not sure why but I'm happy just to have it work for now.)

Comment: Please check the answers to a [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2364/125) to see if they work for you.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Feel free to answer your own question  (your first answer on this site!) with the above and include screenshots so that it is helpful to others. You might not be able to upload the image yet (need 10 rep), but if you upload it and just leave the link in the body, one of us will upload it for you.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open up the Options Inspector (Format menu)
2. Select Global Preferences in the first pull-down menu
3. Search for "DefaultStyle..."
4. When "DefaultStyleDefinitions" appears under the Global Options/File Locations, click on the wrench/hammer icon
5. Select "NaturalColor.nb" in the "Creative" folder in the StyleSheets folder.

(For reasons I don't understand, you cannot directly navigate to Global Options/File Locations/Default... If you do, the wrench/hammer icon is grayed out. But if you search, it is clickable.)

Thanks @rm -rf for your help

Comment: +1 for answering your own question for the benefit of the community

Comment: On my installation, the path to the stylesheet you want (make sure "Creative" is in your path, there is more than one "NaturalColor.nb") is:

/Applications/Mathematica.app//SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Creative/NaturalColor.nb