# How to change default font for all existing notebooks at once?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, fonts

By default, Mathematica 9 and 10 use Gill Sans MT fonts for headings of title/subtitle/section/subsection/subsubsection. Unfortunately, Gill Sans MT fonts have no Cyrillic letters, so that all headings in my old notebooks have become corrupted. I found one remedy. After uninstalling Gill Sans fonts from OS,  Mathematica substitutes the absent fonts with something else which turns out to have Cyrillic letters.

**Is there a less radical solution?**

Setting individual stylesheets for every notebooks (as explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html)) is not an option for me.

Comment: The combination of [11766](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11779/1063) and [9942](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9943/1063) should largely solve your problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which operating system were you on?

Comment: @JohnFultz: I observed this problem on Windows 7/8.1/10.

Answer (score -1):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, StyleHints -> {"CodeFont" -> "Courier"}]
```