# Default window size too small in version 12.3 (in Windows 10)

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, version-12.3

After starting Mathematica 12.3, the default window size is like this, it's too small for me,  I don’t want to manually drag the window every time. I have tried [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/opening-new-notebooks-with-a-non-default-window-size),

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, WindowSize -> {800, 800}]
```

and change "Options Inspector", these are no longer valid, only `SetOptions[InputNotebook[], WindowSize -> {800,800}]` works, I added it to "init.m", but each time is delayed to take effect, I don't like this solution. I hope there is a simple way to return to the previous behavior.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this approach fit your needs? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100432/5478

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, but only works on latest macOS Ventura.

Open the stage manager:
[image]

Change the setting to this:
[image]

then reopen Mathematica ,the default notebook should centered

[image]